# Laravel: Get value of radiobutton in blade and put it in database with AuthController.php

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

So have an issue with putting the values of my radiobuttons in my database with AuthController. I want to simply let the user choose between male, female and other (values 1,2 and 9) in the Laravel registration form (register.blade.php).
But whatever I try my value keeps returning 0 in my database.

this is my blade:

```
{{ Form::radio('sex', 1, true, ['class' => 'grid__offset-bp1-2']) }}male<br>
{{ Form::radio('sex', 2, false, ['class' => 'grid__offset-bp1-2']) }}female<br>
{{ Form::radio('sex', 9, false, ['class' => 'grid__offset-bp1-2']) }}other
```

and this is my AuthController.php:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name_first' => $data['name_first'],
            'name_second' => $data['name_second'],
            'name_last' => $data['name_last'],

            'sex' => $data['sex'],

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            //'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
            'phone' => $data['phone']
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: There's a lot that could be going wrong and you're not showing us the controller logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the User Model?
Maybe you forgot the 'sex' field in the Model

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to put 'sex in the fillable (user.php)